# Consecutive questions in DialogFlow ES

Tags: dialogflow-es

What's the best way in Dialogflow-ES console to ask two consecutive questions regardless of the answer to the first question? I want to force a follow up question and trying to avoid using the API for this (and call an event).

Using context and follow-up intent is not enough, as it often selects another intent out of context that happens to match the answer to the first question in some way. Also, I think parameters can't be used for this unless there is a way to capture a parameter that is any kind of text string since the user is able to type anything as question 1 answer.